# Publishing .bag file for different nodes

Tags: ros, python, rosbag, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Let's say I have two topics publishing data:

`/chatter1`

`/chatter1`

These two topics are currently saving to a `rosbag` file as they publish the data. I'm creating another node which extracts the features. I therefore need to create a node that subscribes to the `.bag` file and then writes these to an array which I can then use for extracting the features from.

Is this possible in ros? And can anyone offer any tutorials on this?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/111906/publishing-.bag-file-for-different-nodes/) by [Phorce](https://answers.ros.org/users/9496/phorce/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2013-12-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, you can subscribe to `/chatter1` and `/chatter1` with a node while rosbag is running. You can have many subscriber to one publisher.

---

Originally posted by [David Galdeano](https://answers.ros.org/users/9481/david-galdeano/) with karma: 357 on 2013-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Phorce](https://answers.ros.org/users/9496/phorce/) on 2013-12-19**:
@galdeano Hey thanks. How would I open (or get access) to the data inside the rosbag file that is recording to `/chatter1` and `/chatter2` whilst it is running though?

**Comment by [David Galdeano](https://answers.ros.org/users/9481/david-galdeano/) on 2013-12-19**:
I do not understand, why would you access the data on the rosbag file, while you have the real time data published?

If you still need to manipulate bag files, use:
http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API#cpp_api

but as said in the begin of the document:

```
 'Note that the rosbag API's are not thread-safe for reading and writing any given bag file. Users of the APIs must ensure no concurrent input/output operations are performed on different threads.'
```

So you can't read and write at the same time.

**Comment by [Phorce](https://answers.ros.org/users/9496/phorce/) on 2013-12-19**:
@galdeano - Very valid point. I've misunderstood. But, I do not know of a way to subscribe to multiple topics in Python and being able to store this data inside a numpy array? The problem is that, using rosbag it takes both data of the nodes and combines them. I need a way to do this

**Comment by [David Galdeano](https://answers.ros.org/users/9481/david-galdeano/) on 2013-12-19**:
For numpy use:
http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/numpy

For syncronisation of several topics use:
http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#Policy-Based_Synchronizer_.5BROS_1.1.2B-.5D

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you asking how to subscribe to two topics with one node?

You can simply create multiple Subscribers, so in the tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29

```
ros::Subscriber sub1 = n.subscribe("chatter1", 1000, chatterCallback1);
ros::Subscriber sub2 = n.subscribe("chatter2", 1000, chatterCallback2);
```

and similarly in python.

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2013-12-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1